# Debugging in VS 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Hi there I have this upgraded vb.net project from vb 2005. Now everytime I debug then proceed to press F10 or F11, it goes randomly a different line. For example I debug it at line 23, then I pressed F10/11 it will go to line 20 or somewhere nonsense to the code. I've read somewhere that this is an issue. Anyone?

Here's the link for the issue I've read.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/8543248-make-the-debugger-stick-to-the-current-thread-inst

Comment: This is due to multithreading, you can select which thread you want to track at the top, where it should say `Main Worker` ect.

Comment: Hi Jaxi. I'm a newbie when it comes to vs2015. I'd like to know to do that. Thanks!